# How to save a timestamp using NodaTime?

Tags: datetime, datetimeoffset, nodatime

I have the following implementation using basic UtcNow, and then converting it back to the UI.
The purpose in this scenario is very simple.
When I insert a new client to the database, I convert it to UtcNow, so I have a timestamp of this record.
When I show it back to the user, I convert it to Local (eg: You are member since "dd/MM/yyyy").

Here is my implementation. I would like to know how do I get this done through NodaTime. And also, if anyone has a better approach for doing it, I'll be glad to hear!

```cs
public interface IDateTime
{
    DateTime ToUtcNow { get; }
    DateTime FromUtc(DateTime dateTimeToConvert);
}

public class DateTimeProvider : IDateTime
{
    public DateTime ToUtcNow
    {
        get { return DateTime.UtcNow; }
    }

    public DateTime FromUtc(DateTime dateTimeToConvert)
    {
        return dateTimeToConvert.ToLocalTime();
    }
}
```

Also, how should I save it to database, in this case Sql Server. What data type should I use? DateTime, DateTimeOffset? What about in code? OffsetDateTime, ZonedDateTime I am very confused about that. I have read the userguide, but it shows more complex scenarios that I'am not getting to implement it in such a simple scenario.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to store points in time, regardless of calendar system or time zone. Those are represented by `Instant` values in Noda Time. So within most of your code, that's probably what you should use to represent the timestamp. (That's also what `IClock.Now` will give you.)

However, your database is unlikely to know about Noda Time... I would suggest that you should probably store a `DateTimeOffset`, which you can obtain via `Instant.ToDateTimeOffset` (and there's `Instant.FromDateTimeOffset` too). That will always have an offset of 0, but at least then it's not ambiguous about which point in time it represents.